# Cordova IOS 13.6.1 Video does not Blur

Tags: javascript, html, css, ios, webrtc

I am using Cordova plugin (https://github.com/cordova-rtc/cordova-plugin-iosrtc)  along with https://apirtc.com/ product for WebRTC in our Cordova IOS/Android applications. When the app goes in background (is minimized), i am sending a message from one to the other client (that the app has been minimized), so the client that is not minimized blurs the video of the client whose app is minimized.
I have this HTML where i am putting the local and remote videos

```
<div class="videosArea">
<div id="remote-container"></div>
<div id="local-container"></div>
</div>
```

Also i have this css which i am applying

```
.blur-on-minimize {
opacity: 0.5;
filter: blur(10px);
-webkit-filter: blur(10px);
-moz-filter: blur(10px);
-o-filter: blur(10px);
-ms-filter: blur(10px);
}
```

In the JS, i have this code to handle minimization of the app

```
session.on('contactMessage', function(e) {
if (e.content === 'VideoPaused') {
   $( "#remote-container" ).addClass( "blur-on-minimize" )
   // $( "#remote-container" ).hide()
}  else if (e.content === 'VideoResumed') {
   $( "#remote-container" ).removeClass( "blur-on-minimize" )
   // $( "#remote-container" ).show()
}
   Logger.info(`Received message ${e.content} from ${e.sender.getId()}`)
});
```

This adding and removing of class does not work on IOS element, but it works fine on Browser and Android.

Any idea why is this happening?

UPDATE:I also tried to add class

```
.blur-on-minimize {
    display:none;
}
```

according to the documentation below. It seems that this still does not work on IOS
https://github.com/cordova-rtc/cordova-plugin-iosrtc/blob/master/docs/videoCSS.md

Answer (score 0):

I Solved this by invoking the refresh function for IOS
https://github.com/cordova-rtc/cordova-plugin-iosrtc/blob/master/docs/iosrtc.md#iosrtcrefreshvideos

```
session.on('contactMessage', function(e) {
                    if (e.content === 'VideoPaused') {
                        $( "#remote-container video" ).addClass( "blur-on-minimize" )
                        if (Meteor.isCordova && Meteor.isIos) {
                            cordova.plugins.iosrtc.refreshVideos()
                        }
                    } else if (e.content === 'VideoResumed') {
                        $( "#remote-container video" ).removeClass( "blur-on-minimize" )
                        if (Meteor.isCordova && Meteor.isIos) {
                            cordova.plugins.iosrtc.refreshVideos()
                        }
                    }
                    Logger.info(`Received message ${e.content} from ${e.sender.getId()}`)
                });
```

Keep in mind that Blur is not possible, you can only do the properties listed here
https://github.com/cordova-rtc/cordova-plugin-iosrtc/blob/master/docs/videoCSS.md